# Custom function inside ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I created a custom function to calculate a distance between two points using their latitude and longitude.

So, if I run a single line formula like this, it works fine:

```
=greatCircle(C3,D3,E3,F3)
```

But, trying to apply an ArrayFormula function, to calculate an entire column, doesn't work. Here is the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(greatCircle(C3:C132,D3:D132,E3:E132,F3:F132))
```

Is there any way to run a custom function inside an ArrayFormula?

Here's what I've tried in order to handle arrays, like from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125835/how-to-use-custom-function-with-arrayformula):

```
function greatCircle(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  if (lat1.map) {
    return lat1.map(greatCircle); // Recurse over array if lat1 is array
  } else {
    // Handle single-arguments...
  }
}
```

Comment: This custom function is used in several spreadsheets. I need it to work as simple as possible. This is why I'm looking for a possible solution without changing the custom function.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125835/how-to-use-custom-function-with-arrayformula

Comment: I tried to adapt my function greatCircle(). It looks like it's returning an array now, but all results are #NUM! Would you mind to take a look in what I'm doing wrong? Here is the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HtmspN_pImplN1D6B9p9r0y3VUalHeXLN1D1Xfshe9I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with re-using the function. The issue is that `Array#map` doesn't really work with multiple arrays like you had it. The simplest thing for this is to add the results in an array with a `for` loop and return it when you're done.

Here's the partial function:

```js
function greatCircle(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
{
  // To check for an array, use Array.isArray
  if (Array.isArray(lat1))
  {
    // Column is actually an array of single-element arrays.
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lat1.length; i++)
    {
      // Remember to push an array since we want to return a column
      result.push(
      [ 
        greatCircle(
          // To get a number from the column, you want the first element of the array
          // While we could also have just made this yet another recursive call,
          //  that would have made the code harder to understand
          lat1[i][0], lon1[i][0], 
          lat2[i][0], lon2[i][0]
        ) 
      ]);
    }
      
    return result;
  }
  else if (typeof lat1 === 'number')
  {
    // Your implementation for single-valued arguments:
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also, there is no need for `ARRAYFORMULA` when calling custom functions that take arrays. Just this will do:

```
greatCircle(C3:C132,D3:D132,E3:E132,F3:F132)
```